# asyncio, multiprocessing and websockets not returning a result

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am trying to get websockets, asyncio and multiprocess to work together. I have been stuck on this for 2 days and could appreciate some help.

I have searched for websockets asyncio and multiprocessing on stackoverflow as well as general internet searches. I have found threading examples, which I can make work.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import threading


class Connection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        sock_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.new_loop) 
        sock_thread.start()
        self.x = 0

    async def connect_to_socket(self):
        self.websocket = await websockets.connect('ws://demos.kaazing.com/echo')
        await self.websocket.send("hello")
        response = await self.websocket.recv()
        print(response)


    async def listen_to_socket(self):
         while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            print('Listening for a message...')
            while self.x < 5:
                message = await self.websocket.recv()
                print("< {}".format(message))
                print('\n\n')
                print(self.x)
                self.x += 1
            self.task.cancel()
            self.loop.close()


    def stop(self):
        print('canceling task\n\n')
        self.x = 0
        self.task.cancel()


    def new_loop(self):
        self.task = self.loop.create_task(self.connect_to_socket())
        self.loop.run_forever()


    def make_task(self):
        self.task = self.loop.create_task(self.listen_to_socket())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn=Connection()
```

This works with no issues. I have seen examples where multiprocessing opens a process in an event loop, this is not what I want. I want to ope However, this is not what I want. I want to open a new process and run an event loop in the new process. Inside the event loop, I want to run my sockets. I want to free my main process from listening to sockets and use a child process to listen to the sockets while I do computationally expensive work on my main process.

When I try the following code. I get nothing.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import multiprocessing


class Connection(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, tasks, results):
        super().__init__()
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.results = results
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        print('create event loop')
        self.x = 0
        self.task = self.loop.create_task(self.test())
        print('done with connecting')


    #connect to socket and get response
    async def test(self):
        self.ws = await websockets.connect('ws://demos.kaazing.com/echo')
        await self.websocket.send("hello")
        response = await self.websocket.recv()
        print(response)


    #listen to socket long term after connection
    async def listen_to_socket(self):

        while True:
           await asyncio.sleep(0)

           print('Listening for a message...')
           while self.x < 5:
               await self.websocket.send("hello")
               message = await self.websocket.recv()
               print("< {}".format(message))
               print('\n\n')
               print(self.x)
               self.x += 1
               self.results.put(message)
           self.task.cancel()
           self.loop.close()


    #stop task
    def stop(self):
        print('canceling task\n\n')
        self.x = 0
        self.task.cancel()


    # listen to socket long term
    #I have not called this as I can't even get a response from test()
    def make_task(self):
        self.task = self.loop.create_task(self.listen_to_socket())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()
    process = Connection(tasks, results)
    if tasks.empty():
        print('empty')

    else: 
        print(tasks.get())
```

I expect to connect with the socket and receive a response. However, I get nothing. I get no error messages,no printout from the connection, I get an empty queue and that's all. How do I get the return values from my websocket?
I am still new enough, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any advice would help me out. 
Thank you

Comment: You are not starting the event loop in the process version. In your threaded example you have `self.loop.run_forever()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wasn't able to get it to run, even starting a loop, so I just found a simple example and have been adding to it. It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested, I got this to work. It is very much a work in progress and I am adding to it, and since this is for me and relatively simple, I didn't comment it. 
I started with the code from this answer and built on it.

[Python3 Websockets / Multithreading issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433318/python3-websockets-multithreading-issue)

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing

class connect():
    def __init__(self, results, tasks):
        self.x = 0
        self.results = results
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    async def commander_start(self):
        while not self.tasks.empty():
            self.uri = self.tasks.get()
            self.tasks.task_done()
            self.ws = await websockets.connect(self.uri)
            while True:
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
                print('Listening for a message...')
                while self.x < 5:
                    await self.ws.send("hello")
                    message = await self.ws.recv()
                    message = message+str(self.x)
                    print("< {}".format(message))
                    print('\n\n')
                    print(self.x)
                    self.x += 1
                    self.results.put(message)    
                self.ws.close()
                self.x = 0
                print('ws clsed')
                self.task.cancel()
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                self.loop.close()


    def run_commander(self):
        self.task = self.loop.create_task(self.commander_start())
        self.loop.run_forever()


    def main(self):
        self.commander = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run_commander)
        self.commander.start()
        time.sleep(3)
        self.commander.kill()


        print('is alive:', self.commander, self.commander.is_alive())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size_q = 10

    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue(maxsize=size_q)
    results = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=size_q)
    conn = connect(results,tasks)
    tasks.put('ws://demos.kaazing.com/echo')

    conn.main()
    print('tasks2 put')
    tasks.put('wss://echo.websocket.org')
    conn.main()
    if not results.empty():
        for x in range(size_q):
            print(results.get())
```

There is a bunch I am going to change and improve, I just wanted the base system to work so I could build from there, so that anyone that uses this will need to modify it to suit their needs. For instance, I spawn a new process and kill it, instead of running a continuous process and giving it work to do, I also am trying to figure out the specifics of the joinable queue and how to use it to add jobs after the process and event loop has been created.